# Java write to .csv file

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to write to a .csv file, but I keep getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    void is an invalid type for the variable writeToFile
    Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
    Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
```

The error is associated with the line:

```
void writeToFile(String Filename){
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class writeFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        void writeToFile(String Filename){
            double steps=0;
            File file=new File(Filename);
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(file);
            try {
                //Integrate integrate=new Integrate();
                //for (steps=10;steps<1000000;steps=steps*10){
                    //double area_value=integrate.integrate_function(steps);
                    writer.write("Steps"+","+"Area");
                    //}
                //System.out.println(area_value);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I can't see any syntax errors.

Taking into account Reimeus' comment below I edited it a bit. I now have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;

void writeToFile(String Filename){
public class writeFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            double steps=0;
```

etc.

I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Filename cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: _a big red X beside the line_: It would help if you posted the actual error. It looks like you need to move `createNewFile` & the `writer` creation statement into your try/catch block

Comment: Thanks Reimeus. Do you mean within the catch statement?

Comment: 1. Note to self: learn java.
2. Note to self: actually learn java.
3. Do not try to write nested methods in Java because nested methods are not supported by java.

Comment: @DwB clearly that's what I'm trying to do. Or are only those who don't need to ask questions allowed to ask questions?

Answer (score 3):

Java doesnt support nested methods. Move `writeToFile` out of the `main` method

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        writeToFile("c:\\abc.csv");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
    static public void writeToFile(String Filename) throws IOException 
    {
      .
      .
      .
      .
    }
}
```